# Python - posting checkbox to web form

Tags: python, webforms, checkbox, urllib2

i use this code in python to post something to a form in a web page.
but i dont just want to send some text as an input textbox, i also want to decide if a checkbox in the form is checked or not.
what value do i have to give to the 'checkbox' parameter in the "web_form"?

```
web_form = [('textbox', text),('checkbox', ?????)]
form_data = urllib.urlencode(web_form)
o = urllib2.build_opener(url)
res = o.open(url, form_data).read()
```

this is the html of the form:

```
<form action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="textbox"></textarea> Checkbox <input type='checkbox' name='cb' > <input type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is pretty broad since you did not mention with web framework you are using.
Application code could check either for the existence of the checkbox key in the request or check for a particular value...unless you provide further informations: try setting it to something like '1' and see what's happening.

Comment: ah sorry.this is the form html:<form action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="textbox"></textarea>
    Checkbox <input type='checkbox' name='cb' >
 <input type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
</form>